# Is function continuous $x\sin(y)/(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I have the following function and I can't seem to prove that it is **not** continuous:
$
 f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & {(x,y) = (0,0)} \\
x\sin(y)/(x^2+y^2), & \text{else}  \\
\end{cases}$

Comment: Choose 2 lines passing through (0,0), and show that limit along the 2 lines are different.

Comment: Remember that even though a function is defined everywhere doesn't mean that it's continuous.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Taylor series:
$$\sin x\sim_0x$$
we find
$$f(x,x)\sim_0\frac12\quad;\quad f(x,2x)\sim_01$$
so $f$ isn't continuous at $(0,0)$. Obviously $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

Answer (score 2):

along the path $y=mx$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(mx)}{x(1+m^2)}=\frac{m}{1+m^2}$$
which depends on $m$, so discontinous at $(0,0)$

Answer (score 2):

Take the sequence $(x_n,y_n)=(e^{-n},e^{-n})$ which converges to $(0,0)$, however $f(x_n,y_n)$ explodes to $+\infty$. Therefore, $f(x)$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

$\lim\limits_{n \to +oo } \dfrac{e^{-n}sin(e^{-n})}{2e^{-2n}}=\lim\limits_{n \to +oo } \dfrac{sin(e^{-n})}{e^{-2n}}=+\infty$

Remember that: A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is continuous at a point $z_o \in A$ if and only if for every sequence $ {(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}}$ converging at $z_o$, $f(z_n) \rightarrow f(z_o)$.

There is your proof (counter-example)! Hope it helps...